# getserversideprops is returning object which is unable to iterate

Tags: javascript, node.js, iterator

```js
OrdersDashboard.auth = true;
export async function getServerSideProps() {
  await db.connect();
  const data = await Order.find().lean();
  const orders = data.map(db.convertdoctoobj);
  await db.disconnect();
  return {
    props: {
      orders: orders,
    },
  };
}
```

this is my serversideprops

i wanted to get array of the objects of my database but i am unable to show it as object and it is declared as object when trying to iterate the error says "orders.map() is not a function"`

Comment: Well, seems like your `orders` are now what you think they are. Which library are you using for the db here?

Comment: it is an array of data in my MongoDB cluster ,before when I iterated the array of objects it didn't had other arrays as children but now the object have another array of objects

Comment: Where is your error thrown? please attach it and add more information